# For loop is 'printed' every time I hit refresh

Tags: python, cherrypy, jinja2

I build simple webpage using CherryPy and Jinja2

The webserver python file:

```
import cherrypy
from jinja2 import Environment, FileSystemLoader
from soltyslib import listFiles
env = Environment(loader=FileSystemLoader('templates'))
class HelloWorld(object):   
    @cherrypy.expose        
    def index(self):        
        template = env.get_template('index.html')
        result = template.render(name='Pawel',files=listFiles('templates'))
        return result    

cherrypy.quickstart(HelloWorld())
```

Template file:

```
Hello {{name}}!
<ul>
{% for file in files %}
    <li>{{file}}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Ok, and then I run webserver, I go to 127.0.0.1:8080 and see result that is expected:

> Hello Pawel!
>
> - templates\index.html
> - templates\list.html

But then I hit refresh in browser and this is a result:

> Hello Pawel!
>
> - templates\index.html
> - templates\list.html
> - templates\index.html
> - templates\list.html

Why? for loop is evaluated again? How to prevent from doing so?

And in case somebody wondering how listFiles function looks:

```
import os,sys
from collections import deque
def listFiles(cdir, fileslist=[]):
    basedir = cdir
    queuedir = deque()
    queuedir.append(basedir)
    while len(queuedir) > 0:
        currentbase = queuedir.popleft()
        for f in os.listdir(currentbase):
            f = os.path.join(currentbase,f)
            if os.path.isdir(f):           
                queuedir.append(f)
            else:
                fileslist.append(f)

    return fileslist
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is

```
 def listFiles(cdir, fileslist=[]):
```

You're reusing the same list on every call, because default arguments are evaluated only when the function is defined, not every time it's called. See ["Least Astonishment" and the Mutable Default Argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-in-python-the-mutable-default-argument) for a long discussion if this behavior.

Do

```
 def listFiles(cdir, fileslist=None):
     if fileslist is None:
         fileslist = []
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in `fileslist=[]` in the function declaration.  Default values are only ever evaluated once, which means that the list is created the first call, but never rebuilt or cleared.

Answer (score 0):

It's the default kwarg for `fileslist` in `listFiles`.  That list is created once at module load time and keeps accruing items as you append.